# TcpClient class in c++ (Microsoft Visual Studio) example?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, network-programming

I feel so embarrassed it's really a newbie question.
I usually using sys/socket in Linux / Osx to get tcp networking work.
In windows I didn't have clue about it.

I've already made this code running in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class HelloWorld
{
    const String ipAddress = "192.168.2.81";
    static TcpClient tcpClient;
    static NetworkStream networkStream;

    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");

        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, 9090);

        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        networkStream.WriteTimeout = -1;

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client Connected to: " + ipAddress);
        networkStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        byte[] data1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Action1");

        while(true) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            networkStream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

When I look into the msdn [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), it does supporting c++. But when I put it, the studio can't understand TcpClient. Usually we need to put some header in it. But in the documentation there is no header to include. So i'm confuse how can I use TcpClient in c++ then? Am I missing something from the documentation, since i'm new at this?

Comment: @Tony D So it's some different c++. Thanks for the tip. I'll google it.

Comment: FWIW, there are a lot of networking libraries for C++, but no such functionality in the C++ Standard Library itself.  Still, "boost asio" is a popular choice if you're after a "bells and whistles" higher-level lib.  (Still, library recommendations are off-topic on S.O., so I'm leaving it at that.)

Comment: @Tony D. I think your first comment is my solution. It's pretty the same with socket. Since i'm already fluent with it in Linux, so i'm stick with this first. I'll check the boost asio later. Maybe you could copy-paste it as an answer and i'll check it out as the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There are just enough subtle differences to make writing portable code tedious, though most of the nastier differences affect server code more than client; do check the online docs as you use the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TcpClient` does not support proper C++ - it can be used from something Microsoft call *"managed C++"* which is a hybrid of C++ and .NET features. In you want a real C++ TCP client - using an approximation of the BSD API you'll know from Linux - do a little googling for *"C++ winsock client example"* - e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Reproducing code in case link dies:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```